# A simple SDL application does not work with x64 configuration using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, 64-bit, sdl

I coded a simple application using SDL which displays a simple window on Windows 8 (64 bits). In a first time I compiled and executed my code with Win32 configuration (default configuration) and the program works perfectly. Now I want to have the same execution but this time with x64 configuration. So I configured Visual using 'configurations manager' in my project properties and change my SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib choosing x64 libraries in the linker. The project compilation is ok but the execution fails saying that the application has failed to start properly. Here's a screen of the message (the memory address is always the same at each execution) :

[image]

And my c++ code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#define WIDTH 500
#define HEIGHT 500

static float angle = 0.0f;

static void eventListener(SDL_Event *pEvent, bool *pContinue)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(pEvent))
    {
        switch(pEvent->type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                *pContinue = false;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (pEvent->key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        *pContinue = false;
                        break;
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}

#undef main

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Event myEvent;
    bool isAlive = true;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Simple SDL window", NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

    while (isAlive == true)
    {
        eventListener(&myEvent, &isAlive);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return (0);
}
```

I don't understand this message which is not precise. However my x64 SDL libraries linked to my project seems to be correct because the compilation is ok. So I wonder what's happening here. Does anyone already have encountered the same problem ?

Comment: Are you using the same libraries for 32 and 64 bit builds? If yes, probably that is the problem: you're trying to run a 64 bit binary with a 32 bit library. Double check it, please.

Comment: No I'm sure that is x64 libraries. That's why I'm going to be crazy! I tried with win32 and SDL methods are not recognized. Until here it's normal. But if I link with x64 libraries the compilation works (so my SDL methods are recognized) but the execution fails.

Comment: Are the 64 bit SDL libraries at the same directory as the compiled binaries? Maybe Windows is loading the wrong libraries... Also, could you please translate exactly what the message says? I barely speak my own language... hehehe.

Comment: The message says : "The application has failed to start properly (0xc000007b)". Click on 'OK' to close the application". Maybe I should download another version of SDL. I'll let you know tomorrow. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot. Just wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just googled for your error message, and it says that this error code (0x0c000007b) means `INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`.

This means that either you are mixing 32 and 64 bit binaries or you have corrupted binaries. Try to place you binary and your dependencies at the same folder and run the application. If the error continues, than one of your libraries must be corrupted. Else, it was a problem with the Windows loading a library for a different platform of your compiled binary.